# cp hundreds of files to different directories

Tags: bash, sorting, sh, cp

The title not might be the best, I apologize, I'm rather new to scripting.

I'm trying to copy 2 files from each directory and place these compounds in a separate directory that only shares directory names.

for clarity;

```
/path/to/directory/all/variable_directories/
```

Inside this directory will be multiple files, I need 2 files which will have the same name in every individual variable directory.

I am trying to copy these 2 files from each individual variable directory and put them in variable directories based on the basename of /variable_directory/

the copy destination will be;

```
/path/to/magical/shit/subset/set_with_variable_name/variable_directories/
```

Only some of the destination directories are located in each /set_with_variable_name/

The script will need to be able to go through each /set_with_variable_name/ until it finds the directory that shares the basename of the directory that these files are originally being cp'd from

There's about 100 directories
to cp from and to and about 200 files total that need to be copied and sorted appropriately.

I can get it to cp ALL the files to the SAME directory using;

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
for i in */;
do cd $i;
cp filename /path/to/destination/;
cp other_filename /path/to/destination/;
cd ..;
done;
```

It's the sorting the files to the correct destinations that I am completely lost at.

I appreciate any help, I'm a novice to this type of scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need something like that.

```
# looping through all the variable directories
for var_dir in <path1>/all/*; do

    # creating the destination directory if not exists
    mkdir -p "<path2>/set_with_variable_name/$(basename ${var_dir})"

    # copying the first file
    cp "${var_dir}/filename1" "<path2>/set_with_variable_name/$(basename ${var_dir})/filename1"

    # and the second
    cp "${var_dir}/filename2" "<path2>/set_with_variable_name/$(basename ${var_dir})/filename2"
done
```